# ANR errors --› ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut

Tags: android

I have got this reported under an ANR error in my Dev Console. Do I need to spawn a worker thread off `onSignalStrengthsChanged` in my Service to stop ANR for long sql queries?

I also cant tell if this is a mutex lock, but I access my db only through a `ContentProvider`.

Is this an ANR for a long query or a mutex lock ANR?

> DALVIK THREADS: (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
>    "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0
>    obj=0x4002a278 self=0xcf50   | sysTid=9149 nice=0 sched=0/0

```
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method) 
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
at kenyu73.realsignal.DatabaseProvider.insert(DatabaseProvider.java:55)  
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:198)
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:618)  
at kenyu73.realsignal.DatabaseWrapper.insert(DatabaseWrapper.java:189)
at kenyu73.realsignal.SignalStats.updateDbStats(SignalStats.java:154) 
at kenyu73.realsignal.SignalStats.updateSignalStats(SignalStats.java:116)
at kenyu73.realsignal.RealSignalService$2.onSignalStrengthsChanged(RealSignalService.java:156)
at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:329)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)   
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695)   
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)   
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)   
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

the content provider query default is run in the ui thread, so suggestion make a new thread to  do the query work.

also, the `mutex lock` when try to get the lock which has be locked will used times, but if only one thread, the lock maybe be not necessary.